# Rails: look up model by multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have a user model with attributes `firstname` and `lastname`. Instead of looking up users by id, is there a way I can look them up by firstname lastname pairs? There can be duplicate first names and duplicate last names; however, I don't allow for there to be duplicate firstname-lastname pairs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4: `User.find_by(firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Smith")`

Otherwise: `User.where(firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Smith").first()`